# Do we need separate tags for different sites?

Tags: discussion, tags

I mostly moderate on SE and a little on another site, so I'm not entirely sure how moderation varies from site to site.  Nonetheless, should we have separate tags for the "most common" sites in which moderation is greatly emphasized and "sophisticated"?

For instance, should *specific* questions about moderating SE sites be given such a tag?  We must keep in mind that this site is for *all* moderation communities, not just SE.  Some of these may even involve more specific questions, but ones that can still benefit other moderators.

Comment: Note that [this isn't Stack Exchange Moderators SE](http://meta.moderators.stackexchange.com/questions/5/what-is-the-core-mission-of-moderators-stackexchange-com). If you're thinking of tags for specific *SE* sites, you're on the wrong track.

Comment: @AnnaLear: No, not specific SE sites; *any* non-SE site.

Comment: You should give examples, like: usenet, or irc (which has a tag already).

Comment: @rolfl: If it has a tag already, then that sort of answers my question.

Comment: Note that IRC is a protocol, not a site. There are any number of sites, servers and stand-alone clients that use the IRC protocol.

Answer (score 7):

I could kind of see tags for the bigger sites, say [stackexchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange) or [reddit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit) for example. But what would we do with all the little sites that need tags then? Do we allow tags like [myubercoolwebsite.com](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myubercoolwebsite.com)?

Right now, I'd say leave it as it is, and once we see a pattern we can consider adding tags based on sites. But I'd prefer it if we could identify the types of moderation instead.

Comment: `[stackexchange.se]` seems a tad redundant as a tag.

Comment: @GraceNote Probably, those were the just first two examples that I could think of.

Comment: I more meant that "stackexchange.stackexchange" as the label on the tag seemed redundant.

Comment: @GraceNote Ohhhh, I see it now, I totally missed that. Sort of like saying ATM Machine I guess :)

Comment: I think that if the site is readily known, like reddit, then it's fair

Answer (score 7):

I think that we should let tags build up for a couple of days and edit out the really crappy ones as we go along, so we can feel how things are going to play out and what sites are going to be dominant here.

Comment: That ^ ​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 2):

Is essentially different to moderate a site or other? What moderators need to do in a community doesn't depend on what technology was the community built. Granted, you have different toolsets for each technology, but that's not enough to differentiate what needs to be done when dealing with users.

I would agree with the creation of tags for specific technologies, like IRC, phpbb, etc. if, a big IF, **the question is about the technologies you posses to deal with a situation**. How to deal with an user in a forum, Stack Exchange, IRC, or Facebook, doesn't matter for the people answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps tags for classes of site if they have specific differences in the type of situation they deal with, but for the most part, moderation isn't substantially different from one community to another.  The rules in place may be different, but the basic principals remain largely the same.

If a case can be made that the tag meaningfully differentiates the category, then I wouldn't be opposed, but simply tagging which community it is in regards to is probably generally unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if a user gets enough rep to create a new tag [myubercoolwebsite.com](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myubercoolwebsite.com), they should be allowed to use it - expecting a considerable number of site-specific questions, considering the user somehow got the reputation high enough for creating new tags.

If the site is not *notorious* enough, it's unlikely to yield an asker with reputation high enough to create a tag for it.